# How to access a js file outside the public folder?

Tags: laravel, vue-component

I was trying to register a vue component in the `app.js` file from a laravel project but I just can't seem to find the right path for the `app.js`, there are two files with `app.js` filenames. Here is my file structure:

```
public
        css
        js
               app.js

resources
        js
              components
                     Articles.vue
                     ExampleComponent.Vue
              app.js
              bootstrap.js
```

Here is where I imported my app.js file to my blade file:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <articles>

        </articles>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ assets('js/app.js') }}"></script>


</body>
```

The problem is I want to access the second `app.js` file which is in the `resources` folder, but the above code keeps giving me the first `app.js` file which is in the `public` folder.

I tried giving it the absolute path to the file using this code `URL::asset('resources/js/app.js')`

This gives me a url like `localhost:8000/resources/js/app.js` which is the correct file location but somehow this link leads to a `404` page. So is there any other way to access the file?

Thanks

Comment: `npm run dev` to re-compile changes from `resources/js/app.js` to `public/js/app.js`. Red [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**

`localhost:8000/something` always refer to `something` in the `public` directory. So, you cannot reference your `resource/js/app.js` in your blade file as js file.

**Secondly**

Actually you don't need to use the `resource/js/app.js` file in your blade. If you even do so, the code won't work. Because the codes in `resources/js/app.js` are un-compiled. You need to compile them and use them in blade files. So, where is the compiled file? It's actually the `public/js/app.js` file. This file is the compiled version of your `resource/js/app.js`.

The problem is every time you change a js file inside `resource`, you need to re-compile the js codes. All those codes will be merged together and will be copied in `public/js/app.js`.

**How to compile?**

Before compiling your js code you need to make sure you have installed your frontend dependencies correctly by running the `npm install` command.

Then if all dependencies are installed you can compile your code using the command

`npm run dev` for development level compile

`npm run production` for production level(minified and secured) compile.

If you don't want to run the `npm run dev` command every time you change a file, then you can run `npm run watch` command. This command will watch if any js file changed. If changed it will compile automatically.

Comment: Thank you...i actually tried to run npm run watch and i got some errors and was trying to work without it...now i just need to fix that..Thanks for the explanation